# Using Power Automate To Parse Email and Extract Information From The Body

Tags: power-automate, form, outlook, public-website, parser-error

I have a website that I collect details from and details are submitted via a form that lands into my mailbox. Here are the details:
Question 1:
Other:
Ouestion 1 Details:
Question 1 Details 2:
First Name
Last Name
Address
Town / City
Country
Post Code
Telephone
Email
Type of Form

I want to be able to extract certain details from the body of the email. I attempted to do this with Power Automate but got an error after using this expression for example.

trim(first(split(last(split(body('Html_to_text'),'Question 1')),'Other')))

Any ideas why it isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Your details is also unclear how this thing `Question 1: Other: Ouestion 1 Details: Question 1 Details 2: First Name Last Name Address Town / City Country Post Code Telephone Email Type of Form` was formed. Additionally, you're doing to fast with the entire complex formula at once.

What I can suggest is to run in a `Compose` action, sequentially, then run and check if it throws error.

1. Try this first and test: `split(body('Html_to_text'),'Question 1')` which I suppose should return an array with 2 items `: Other: Ouestion 1 Details:` , and  `Details 2: First Name Last Name Address Town / City Country Post Code Telephone Email Type of Form`.
2. Then gradually add more function and test: `last(split(body('Html_to_text'),'Question 1'))` that should return the last array of no. 1 above.
3. Then try add more and test: `split(last(split(body('Html_to_text'),'Question 1')),'Other')`

Or the better way is to split into multiple `Compose` actions rather than combine into 1.